# A sh line that scares me, is it portable?

Tags: node.js, bash, sh, pm2

I'm currently working on [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), a process manager for NodeJS.

As it's targeted at Javascript, a new standard is coming, ES6. 
To enable it on NodeJS I have to add the option `--harmony`.

Now for the bash part, I have to let the user pass this option to the interpreter that executes the file. By crawling the web (and found on Stackoverflow) I found this :

```
#!/bin/sh

':' //; exec "`command -v nodejs || command -v node`" $PM2_NODE_OPTIONS "$0" "$@"
```

[bin line](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/bin/pm2-harmony#L3)

Looks like a nice hack but is it portable enough ? On CentOS, FreeBSD...

It's kind of critical so I want to be sure.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down the line of interest.

`:` is a do nothing in shells.

`;` is a command separator.

`exec` will replace the current process with the process of the command that it is executing.

Notice that in the exec command it passes `"$0"` and `"$@"` as parameter to the command?

This will allow the new process to read the script denoted by `$0` and use it as a script input and reads the original parameters as well `$@`

The new process will read the input script from the beginning and ignore the comments like `#!/bin/sh`. and will also ignore `:`.

Here's the trick. Most interpreters, including perl, uses syntax that are ignored by shell or vice-versa so that on re-reading the input file, the interpreter will not exec itself again.

In this case, the new process ignored the whole line from `:`. The reason why the rest of the line is ignored? On some c like interpreters, `//` is a comment.

I forgot to answer your question. Yes it seems portable. There may be corner cases but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: Damn this is very smart hack. Thank you for this explanation !

Answer (score 1):

> To enable it on NodeJS I have to add the option --harmony.

Not necessarily. You can use normal "#!/usr/bin/env node" shebang, but set a harmony flags in runtime using [setflags](https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-setflags) module.

I'm not sure it's better solution, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Didn't known this module, good to know for my nodejs toolbox :D Thanks !